# android map draw custom marker

Tags: android, google-maps, overlay

Say I have multiple Overlay items in my map. Is it possible to draw some text (say the overlay number) on the default marker ?

Answer (score 0):

You could define some custom markers. You can't edit the default ones...

Comment: I have the drawable with me, which I use as the marker. How do I customise it to put the text in ?

Comment: you could unse some image editor to create the marker image with the text. and here's how to customize the marker image on google maps: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#SimpleIcons

Comment: the problem is I want the markers to have text generated dynamically. I mean say I have 10 markers on the map, then what If I want each marker marked with different alphabet (like when you search on google maps, and the results are marked with alphabets)

Comment: you can create icons for all the markers and then instead of generating them each time, just pick the right one :)

Comment: :O that would be a painful thing to do :(

Comment: yeah...i'll let you know if i think of a better solution

Answer (score 0):

Create a Textview and use the map layout param (with the position you want it, as it accepts a geopoint) to add it to textview that you created. Add the textview to the mapView
Your text will appear on the map over the marker